# how can I use mitreId openid in a angular and java based project

Tags: java, angularjs, openid

I am fairly new to the openId connect, I want integrate MitreId OpenId connect server in my project that is based on angular and java (servlet), but I have no idea how to integrate.
I read the documentation of mitreId but unable to configure it.
Please help me with some example or link so that I can understand and able to implement.

**Requirement**   When I try to login with app it go to the mitreid openid connect server and authenticate it and return back with token id, scope and role and according to that information app gives the response.

Thanks:

Comment: Can you add code examples of what you have tried, it will help others to help you.

Comment: Hi @Anthropic 
I am trying with simple web app that is provided by mitreid and try to redirect my app url so that I can access the response of my app by parsing the code that I received in url.\